# What does little omega mean here?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

In this paper http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S009753970444435X

they say $m = \omega (n)$. Is this the same as big Omega notation? What does the $\omega$ mean?

Comment: I can't get through the paywall. Could you provide a little more context?

Comment: Yes. The set up is balls into bins. They are throwing $m$ balls into $n$ bins, and say that $m >> n$, which they define to mean $m = \omega(n)$. However, I am not sure what this says about $m$ as $n$ gets large

Answer (score 2):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations):

T.F.A.E.

- $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$
- $f$ dominates $g$ asymptotically
- $\forall k>0 ~\exists n_0~\forall n>n_0~|f(n)|\geq k\cdot |g(n)|$
- $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right|=\infty$